# Ruby/Rails display general screen when modifications being performed on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a ruby on rails app running a server and sometimes it needs to be taken down for updates/etc.  As of now, one way I see to have a general display screen during update periods (when the app is down) is to substitute the files within /srv/www/ directory to just have it display a general screen everywhere that the user could possibly navigate to.  I also thought of having a central controller file that connects all others (essentially a main) but this seems counter intuitive for rails.

There are many external links to these different components of the site that the user could navigate to from outside and I need to make sure that they always receive this general update screen when the app is taken down for a little.

I was wondering if anyone had any other ideas.... maybe a library or something like that, I can't seem to find anything online. any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this Capistrano task:

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :web do
    desc <<-DESC
      Present a maintenance page to visitors. Disables your application's web \
      interface by writing a "maintenance.html" file to each web server. The \
      servers must be configured to detect the presence of this file, and if \
      it is present, always display it instead of performing the request.

      By default, the maintenance page will just say the site is down for \
      "maintenance", and will be back "shortly", but you can customize the \
      page by specifying the REASON and UNTIL environment variables:

        $ cap deploy:web:disable \\
              REASON="a hardware upgrade" \\
              UNTIL="12pm Central Time"

      Further customization will require that you write your own task.
    DESC
    task :disable, :roles => :web do
      require 'erb'
      on_rollback { run "rm #{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html" }

      reason = ENV['REASON']
      deadline = ENV['UNTIL']      
      template = File.read('app/views/admin/maintenance.html.erb')
      page = ERB.new(template).result(binding)

      put page, "#{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html", :mode => 0644
    end
  end
end
```

The `app/views/admin/maintenance.html.erb` file should contain:

```
<p>We’re currently offline for <%= reason ? reason : 'maintenance' %> as of <%= Time.now.utc.strftime('%H:%M %Z') %>.</p>
<p>Sorry for the inconvenience. We’ll be back <%= deadline ? "by #{deadline}" : 'shortly' %>.</p>
```

The final step is to configure the Apache virtual host with some directives to look for the `maintenance.html` file and redirect all requests to it if it's present:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect all requests to the maintenance page if present
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|jpg|png)$
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html -f
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
  RewriteRule ^.*$ /system/maintenance.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

To put the application into maintenance mode, run `cap deploy:web:disable` and to make it live again do `cap deploy:web:enable`.

Comment: Thanks John, please see my comment below

Comment: I tried to set this up and having some issues.  The apache does not seem to redirect to the maintenance page.  I am running the app using mongrel + apache and after reading many websites I am still not sure.  As you said I have a virtual host in apache configured to sit on the specific port and for some reason whether apache is running or not it still displays the app page regardless if I allow or deny access.  Therefore, I obviously cannot make it rewrite to the maintenance page.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I would configure your webserver (nginx or apache) to look for a maintenance.html page and serve that up with a 503 status if it exists. So, taking every URL of your app down is as simple as uploading an .html file and deleting it when it's done.

See [here](http://blog.onehub.com/posts/rails-maintenance-pages-done-right) and [here](http://shiftcommathree.com/articles/make-your-rails-maintenance-page-respond-with-a-503) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano has a bunch of built-in recipes for displaying maintenance pages and is fully integrated with git/subversion. Makes deployment and management a breeze.